# Оптимизация большого количества объектов | unity

Tags: unity3d, procedural-generation

У меня есть очень много однотипных обхектов (больше 2000) по типу: трава, камень, гематит. Соединять combine'ом их нельзя, т.к. они могут быть изменены в любой момент игроком. У меня  есть только 1 вариант и это просто отгружать чанки, но это не особо помагает, т.к. даже 1 чанк очень сильно нагружает систему.

И ещё небольшой вопрос, почему статистика показыввает 200fps хотя на самом деле не больше 20?

Вот скрипт который делает колдунство: (значения seed, amplitude, freq берутся рандомное число из другого скрипта(который только это и делает))

Скрипт на пастебине из за stackoverflow https://pastebin.com/5LTvQiM3

Comment: Я так скажу хотя мой ответ вам может огарчать. 2000 объектов для юнити это много. И вообще не советую создать игру на юнити где будет больше 400 объектов. У каждого объекта как минимум есть своя позиция, свой угл поворота, свой размер. У вас получается 18000 переменных как минимум которые обновляются каждые 0,02 сек. Лично я не вижу способ оптимизации

Comment: Хотя... сколько объектов у вас в 1 чанке?

Comment: Объект не будет влиять на процесс только и только тогда когда он неактивен.

Comment: @AltF4 это "предположение" хоть на чем-то основано? 18000 тысяч переменных? Это целый, давайте посчитаем, `2000 * позиция(12 байт) * Поворот(16 байт) * Масштаб(8 байт)`... ~70 килобайт?Действительно непосильная задача для Unity.